# Unablle to use stdin in Python with Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim

I have previously worked with python 3 in Windows 10 where I prefer using this for reading input and output from my files. This is the syntax I use

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open("input.in", "r")
sys.stdout=open("output.txt","w")
```

Input.in -> for input Output.out for Output 
Now that I have shifted to Ubuntu I find it difficult to read input via Input.in, I created this input.in file using this command in vim

```
sudo vim input.in
wq
```

And now that I am using this file to read any Inputs, I get this error very often 
File "", line 1 
I faced no issues with Windows 10.
I donot know the reason for it But Maybe , I am not able to rightly Make my Input.in File correctly in Ubuntu, If please some one can explain me the issue and tell me the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: 1. Never use `sudo` until you understand in what rare situations you need it. 2. Please show the full text of the error; copy/paste from the terminal and format as code.

Comment: umm ok I , I tried without sudo as well facing same issues , pasting the error

Comment: Still waiting for an error…

Comment: Yeah, I get no error doing this. How are you running the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the error you are facing just use the command mkdir to create a folder then rename it accordingly with .txt and you will be able to do it. do not use sudo bro.